# R : min and max numeric value with name

Tags: r, max, min

```
NAME                                        Number
cars                                         10
people                                       340
bus                                          4
```

I have to find way to rapresent minimum and maximum  numeric value with his correspondent name from first coulmn.

if I put command  :

```
min(data[,2]) 
max(data[,2])
```

the results are only values

the final result should be displayed like :

- for minimum value*

  Bus 4
- for maximum value*

  people 340

Comment: May be you need `which.max`. i.e. `data[which.max(data[,2]),]` and `which.min`

Comment: Yes exactly,  thank you very much Arkun.    data[which.max(data[,2]),]   is good,  but is there way to not rampresent   "Name" and "Number "  only   bus 4 or  people 340 ?

Comment: `unlist(df1[which.max(df1[,2]),], use.names=FALSE)` gets that, but tthe numeric element will be converted to 'character'.  From the output you expected, it is not clear about the structure

Comment: Thank you very much.   How I may create  bar chart by using barplot() command ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BRUny.png    i have this information and I have to create bar chart by using barplot . Could you help me please?

Comment: I think it is just like the one I posted.  `m1 <- t(yourdata[,2]); colnames(m1) <- yourdata[,2]; barplot(m1)`

Comment: m1 <- t(data[,2]); colnames(m1) <- data[,2]; barplot(m1)   this one is good but  down  I dont see the names , just numbers

Comment: and even if  I do                                                                                                          m1 <- t(data[,2]); colnames(m1) <- data[,1]; barplot(m1)   I dont see all names, but 3 of them

Comment: In the example you posted, I am getting the names.  Can you just expand the plot window by clicking on the `+` on the top right

Comment: If the names are really long, then it may be better to substring it or have the labels in two rows (one below the another)

Comment: sure, how do I create the title of this  barplot?                                                   m1 <- t(data[,2]); colnames(m1) <- data[,1]; barplot(m1)

Comment: `barplot(m1, main='A nice barplot')`

Comment: If the names are really long, `colnames(m1) <- sub('(\\S+\\s\\S+)\\s(\\S+\\s\\S+)(.*)', '\\1\n\\2\n\\3', data[,1]); barplot(m1, cex.names=0.7)` would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `min` and `max` rows separately with

```
df1[which.max(df1[,2]),]
```

Or

```
df1[which.min(df1[,2]),]
```

For plotting, may be

```
df2 <- subset(df1, Number %in% c(min(Number), max(Number)))
m1 <- t(df2[,2])
colnames(m1) <- df2[,1]
barplot(m1)
```

#### Update

Using the example in the image,

```
dfN <- data.frame(Col1=c('Controlli di Polizia Giudiziaria', 
'Ricrosi a seguito di contravvenzioni', 
'Ordinanze e inguinzioni sul commercio', 'Automezzi', 
'Chilometri percorsi', 'Infrazioni al codice della strada'),
 number = c(249, 349, 152, 8, 41658 , 8597))

 colnames(m1) <- sub('(\\S+\\s\\S+)\\s(\\S+\\s\\S+)(.*)', 
             '\\1\n\\2\n\\3', dfN[,1])
 barplot(m1, cex.names=0.7)
```